# Angular 4 - how to display newly created variables alphabetically?

Tags: angular, sorting, pipe

I have to display all my reports alphabetically.

```
<ul class="reports-list" style="list-style-type:none;">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let report of reports | sort">
    <li id="report-number-{{report.id}}"><div id="report-button-{{report.id}}" class="btn report-name-button border-bottom standard-color" (click)="chooseReport(report)">{{ report?.name | translate }} </div>
    </li> 
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

I was trying to use this pipe but it doesnt show in that order :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
name: "sort"
     })
 export class ArraySortPipe {
transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
  array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  return array;
}
```

}

Can anybody help me please? Regards.

Comment: Can you post your dummy JSON here for reff.

Comment: Is reports really an Array of string ? since you are  doing "reports.id" in your template I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the property that you want to sort base on it becuase `a,b` parameters are objects

Try like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
name: "sort"
     })
 export class ArraySortPipe {
transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {
 return array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

}
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-sort)

Comment: You code is not logical  the pipe take an array of "string"  so there is no way   a.name would work

Comment: I did not work. It changed the sequence a bit but it's not aphabetically

Comment: @Artamiel can you share with use a json example of your data , have you check the demo ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have "model" for Report   (certainly  with property name and id) your pipe should look like this :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { Report } from 'myModels/report'

@Pipe({
    name: "sort"
})
export class ArraySortPipe {
transform(array: Array<Report>, args: string): Array<Report> {
  array.sort((a: Report, b: Report) => {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.name  > b.name ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });
  return array;
}
}
```

In your code your pipe was taking an array of string but in your template your use "report.id"  it's not logical.

If you don't have Report model just change report by  { id : number, name : string ...}

Futhermore you pipe is doing a huge traitement depending on the array size, perhaps you should make him "pure" for better performance.

```
@Pipe({
    name: "sort",
    pure : true
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-pipes